# The service already exists vstsagent.dev.mycomputername

Tags: azure-devops

I want to create a deployment agent for my project in Azure DevOps.
I installed an agent and then managed to delete it  using

```
./config remove
```

then rebooting
then removing the folder.

When I installed it again I got a message

```
The service already exists: vstsagent.dev.mycomputername, it will be replaced
Could not delete the service 'vstsagent.dev.mycomputername'
```

The deployment group shows as offline in Azure DevOps.

Comment: I think the agent service is not uninstalled completely. Why don't you try to install the agent using a different name? i think this would work

Answer (score 1):

My case may give you some insight. I have tried several times of agent setup, so there's multiple services installed. What I need to do is execute `./config remove` inside EVERY directory to remove all services before a fresh re-install. (So I executed this command 8 times here)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it has been a while since I did this. I don't remember how I solved it... maybe it just takes Azure some time to process things asynchronously.